# How do you add N-number of anchor points to a shape in Figma?

Tags: vector, shapes, figma

Similar to how Adobe Illustrator has the ability to programmatically add N-number of anchor points to a shape or line without having to use the Pen tool to manually place each one, does Figma have a way to add say, 30 anchor points to a line, spaced evenly?

Doing this manually with the Pen tool is both tedious and time-consuming.